# Compare Integers Function SIGSEGV

Tags: c, function, integer, compare, qsort

This is my compare function:

```
int compareInts(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = (const int*)a;
    const int *pb = (const int*)b;
    return *pa - *pb;
}
```

When I pass this function to qsort along with an array of integers:

```
qsort(a, size, sizeof(char*), compareInts);
```

Everything works fine and I get a sorted list. However if I try to use it myself:

```
compareInts(2, 2);
```

I get a SIGSEGV unless I revise the function as follows:

```
int compareInts(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = (const int*)a;
    const int *pb = (const int*)b;
    return pa - pb;
}
```

Which works fine when I call it but when passed to qsort returns an unsorted list!
What's going on here?

Comment: The third parameter to `qsort()` is the size of each element. If you're actually sorting an array of `int` then the third parameter should be `sizeof(int)` or perhaps `sizeof(*a)`.

Comment: '2' is NOT a pointer, the function is expecting two pointers.  so it thinks the '2' is a pointer and treats it as such.  accessing address 2, which is outside the data limits of the process, results in undefined behaviour leading to a seg fault event.  The second version of the program is comparing pointers, rather than what the pointers are pointing at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
int a=2;
int b = 2;
compareInts(&a, &b);
```

Your compare function accepts pointers, not integers directly.
What really happens when you pass two integers in

```
compareInts(2,3);
```

is you are telling this function to go and find your integers at memory address 0x00000002 and 0x00000003 respectively, and these are not valid addresses.

In your revised function, you compare the values of the two pointers 0x00000002 and 0x00000003 without attempting to dereference them, so it does not crash.

Comment: "without attempting to dereference them" --> should be "without passing their *addresses* in your call, rather than just passing the raw value "2" (i.e. the *value* stored in that *address*).  Your function expects an *address*.  OP's problem is occurring *specifically because* he/she attempts to dereference them.

Comment: In your revised function you are comparing values in the pointers. qsort on the other hand, passes two values at a time to compareInts correctly, meaning it does something like compareInts(&arr[i], &arr[j]) and so it works. qsort does not care what compareInts does with the values - it only expects an integer result. If you use the revised function with qsort, you will be comparing memory addresses and not values.

Answer (score 1):

With this code:

```
compareInts(2, 2);
```

You are trying to compare memory location 2 with memory location 2.  This will give you a segment violation simply because you don't have access to memory location 2.  You are not trying to compare two *values* located at memory addresses you have access to - you can't even get to that point before the operating system realizes you do not have access to those locations (and gives you a big SEGV thank-you-for-trying).  You need to compare the *contents of* a memory address you actually have access to.  For example:

```
  int a = 2;   // a is an integer variable, you can take the address of this
  int b = 2;   // ibid

  compareInts(&a, &b);  // now, you are giving your function *the addresses of* a and b
```

Comment: overlap with @DNT -- if you're going to accept one of these as an answer, take his - slow typing day for me.